# Running Threads indefinitely in Java WebApplication where mainthread depends on Session

Tags: java, multithreading, session, wicket

I'd like to run a Thread which sends Request like every 15 minutes checking for updates, waits for response and process the data recieving in the response. I need to controle this thread via web frontend, to start / stop and monitor it. The data which needs to be processed will be validated and stored in local datastore via hibernate. The main Thread resides necessarily in session so obviously the lifetime of the subthread may live through session lifetime. Im not sure how stable it is to rely on this, as it is required that these requests being send and check for updates indefinitely and reliable.

Im not sure if the session which holds the threads keeps alive just because the thread is running. What would be best practice / best design choice ?

Application is running with 
jre1.6
tomcat 7
wicket1.5.6
hibernate3.6
spring 3.1

Comment: May be you need run as service and invoke either servlet (or) Controller to poll and keep it in cache.

Comment: In case I'd build a jar for that and run it as a service on OS outside of the servlet container, monitoring and reliability would be good, but how is it possible to control this service from within the servlet container?